# object relesed, how about its property's?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my question is : i think that there is an error in this code ( it is not my code and i have not a Mac to compile ). this is the code :

```
....

CDAUIView *theView = [[CDAUIView alloc] initWithFrame:rectFrame];

theView.myController = self;
self.view = theView;
[theView autorelease];
```

when theView is released, wha about its property ( myController) ??

thanks for your answers

Comment: Is that code from a book? It sure looks familiar...

Comment: yes, the book of Ali Maher, what do you think about this book ?

Comment: The code you've listed is correct.  What's the actual problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the details behind the properties in question (specifically, whether the properties are declared as `retain`, `copy` or `assign`) — but that code looks fine, given reasonable assumptions. Under normal circumstances, setting a property will retain the object, and releasing the object *might* cause its properties to be released (that will happen if the object is deallocated). In this case, releasing the view shouldn't cause its `myController` to be released, because it's still being owned by `self` here. But even if it were, the release would just be balancing the retain.

An object doesn't retain its instance variables whenever it's retained, and it doesn't release them just because it's released. It retains them when it takes ownership it and releases them when it is ready to relinquish ownership.

Answer (score 0):

If CDAUIView is written correctly, when it gets deallocated it will release any objects that it has retained.

Comment: i am tired, i have not see the autorelease. it's not release. thanks